# Why doesn't my parameter work in my report URL?

Tags: tableau-desktop

Does anyone know of a way to pass parameter values via the URL?

I have a report with one parameter: `Param_RoverID`.

I got the shared link url from the Tableau Server, and tried inserting the parameter with a value like this:

https://testing.rover.nasa.gove/#/site/u/views/distance_travelled_dev_4_13291111916000/DistanceReportdashboard?:display_count=n&:iid=5&:origin=viz_share_link%3FParameters.Param_RoverID%3Dbc827d49-1227-414f-b7bd-42c0f092a74f&:showAppBanner=false&:showVizHome=n

But it's not working.  There are no errors, it just doesn't load data for that particular `RoverID`.

In Tableau Desktop, when I set it in there, the report works fine.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Thanks!